# how to write int value inside the query passing through asp.net

Tags: sql, asp.net

I am having the following exception when passing the query through executereader:

> incorrect syntax near )"...

How do I write the 0 here?
Here's the whole query:

```
string query = "select distinct BillNumber,PatientName,MobileNo,DueAmount from PaymentView where RequestDate between '" + fromDate.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd") + "'  and '" + toDate.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd") + "' and DueAmount>'"+value+"')";
```

Comment: Don't concatenate strings to build your sql query but use parameterized queries to avoid sql injection or localisation issue.

Comment: I see a single quote !

Comment: @Shyju I'm assuming that's wrapped around the date.

Comment: Please don't post your code [as an image](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/3933332), but instead copy/paste any relevant code and use [code formatting](http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting). You've done the same in your other 2 questions. it makes it hard to test your snippet since it needs to be typed in by hand.

Comment: Don't post code as an image. Post more of your code(the entire line would probably help). Use parameters which will fix most of your issues.

Comment: given the whole  qyery

Answer (score 0):

Extra Closing bracket at end of query. Also `DueAmount` should not be wrap into single quotes remove it.

```
and DueAmount>'"+value+"')";
             ------------^
```

**Note :** This may lead to SQL Injection attack, My suggestion is use Sql Parameter.

Comment: thank u so much,a silly mistake,probably the pressure is loading me down :D

Comment: Happy to Help! :)